# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < while creating or opening component in sdl web 8

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

we have upgraded SDL Tridion 2013 HR1 to SDL Web 8 and installed successfully. However, we are facing below error in google console when we are creating new component or opening existing component.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in item.aspx?tcm=16:1
```

[image: Uncaught SyntaxError]

Comment: Any GUI extensions active? Can you try to disable them? Did you try to repair the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of a server-side error ruining the JavaScript file that was supposed to be returned.

You can find out what the exact error is by either clicking on the link to the file on the right-hand side or looking it up on the Network tab.

Alternatively, you can look for *warnings* from ASP.NET in the Application log on the server.

One possible reason for the error is that you have an old GUI extension installed that isn't compatible with the new version.

Comment: we have removed old GUI extension and re-installed, it is working.Thanks for you answers.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you would like to accept this answer, so that anyone who runs into this issue in the future can see what worked for you?